# Add CSS class to posts with certain meta key

Tags: custom-field, menus

I am working on my header navigation and I want to underline the menu item for certain conditions.

I would like to add a CSS class *if*

- the post has the ID 21638, *or*
- the post has the meta value 'bloom'

The meta value is an ACF relationship field.

```
<nav class="header-navigation">
<ul class="header-navigation__list">
    <li <?php if (is_single(21638)) or (metadata_exists('bloom') echo 'class="current-menu-item"' ?>><a href="<?php echo site_url('/labels/bloom') ?>">Bloom</a></li>
</ul>
```

I managed to solve the post ID part, but how do I add condition regarding meta value?

Comment: Did you try changing `or` to `||`?  and you have a parenthesis in the wrong place.  it should be `if ( is_single(21638) || (metadata_exists('bloom') )`

Comment: I've replaced the code with `<?php if ( is_single(21638) or (metadata_exists('bloom') ) ) echo 'class="current-menu-item"' ?>`. VSCode accepts it but I receive an _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)_

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about ACF is it comes with lots of functions to check fields. [Here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) is the manual. Are you creating a meta value in addition to the field and it's value? I'm guessing that you are looking for the value of the bloom field. If that's so then
`get_field('bloom',post->ID)`
should be what you're looking for.
Also as rutec pointed out you closed your if parentheses before the second eval. I'm surprised that doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Hi Alex. I am building my website which displays a couple of record labels and dozens of albums. When you are on a label page, you can see all albums, that have been released under this label. To achieve that, I have setup two CPT's. The first is "labels" where each label is represented by a post. The second CPT is "albums". Every album has an ACF, relationship field where the related label has to be selected.

Comment: In my header navigation, I have a link to the label "Bloom". When you are on it, `( is_single(21638)`, the CSS class is being echoed. I also want the class to be echoed on all "albums" posts that are related to "Bloom", i.e. that have the meta vale "Bloom". I had a look at the manual... Do I somehow have to create an object to achieve that?

Comment: The advanced custom field "record label" has a value of "Bloom"? What do you mean by "meta vale "Bloom""?

Comment: $value = get_field( "record_label" ); if ($value == "Bloom")...